# Can I use a UDF for the search condition in a CONTAINSTABLE function

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I am writing a query that uses the CONTAINSTABLE function.  For the third parameter in the CONTAINSTABLE call, I obtain the search term from a UDF.  If I store the output of this UDF in a local variable and then pass the variable to the CONTAINSTABLE function, it works fine:

```
declare @temp nvarchar(255) = dbo.udf_GenerateTerm()
select *  FROM ContainsTable([TableToSearch], Content, @temp, LANGUAGE 1033)
```

However, if I directly reference the UDF as a CONTAINSTABLE argument, I get a syntax error:

```
select * FROM ContainsTable([TableToSearch], Content, dbo.udf_GenerateTerm(), LANGUAGE 1033)
```

Is there any way around this, or this this a limitation of SQL Server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the SQL Server CONTAINSTABLE operation.
Here is the grammar for CONTAINSTABLE.

```
CONTAINSTABLE ( table , { column_name | ( column_list ) | * } , ' <contains_search_condition> ' 
     [ , LANGUAGE language_term] 
  [ , top_n_by_rank ] 
          )
```

**contains_search_condition** is the part we are interested in. The grammar is defined thus

```
<contains_search_condition> ::= 
    { <simple_term> 
    | <prefix_term> 
    | <generation_term> 
    | <generic_proximity_term> 
    | <custom_proximity_term> 
    |  <weighted_term> 
    } 
    | { ( <contains_search_condition> ) 
    { { AND | & } | { AND NOT | &! } | { OR | | } } 
     <contains_search_condition> [ ...n ] 
    }
```

**simple_term** is made up of a **word**. A word is defined as

> Is a string of characters without spaces or punctuation.

You can review the MSDN documentation on [CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) and [CONTAINSTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx) for more info.